# How can I tell what Picker View throws error?

Tags: debugging, swiftui

I have multiple picker views in my view. Now one of them throws an error because the initial value set for the selected value of the picker does not match any values of the picker's list. I know which picker is causing the issue and how to fix it.

My question is about: how can I tell be reading the error report in the console from Xcode, WHICH of my different pickers is actually throwing the error?

I went through the error report and could not find any reference that would help me narrowing it down.

```
2022-11-20 21:12:11.781932+0100 stuffTracker[97477:7589394] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Menu does not have a valid element for default selection'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001081257ec __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106105144 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010a693e08 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000127002b30 -[UIMenu establishInitialDefaultSingleSelection] + 564
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001271dc768 -[UIButton _updateForAutomaticSelection] + 60
    5   SwiftUI                             0x0000000110c3bfe0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_6 + 18612
    6   SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b8d0e8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 144124
    7   SwiftUI                             0x00000001105dfbac OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 14316
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00000001105dfacc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 14092
    9   SwiftUI                             0x0000000110968f68 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 4712
    10  SwiftUI                             0x00000001105df964 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 13732
    11  SwiftUI                             0x00000001105dedc4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 10756
    12  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd96bec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_4 + 27032
    13  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    14  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    15  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    16  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00000001105e02fc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 16188
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00000001105e042c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 16492
    19  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd96bec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_4 + 27032
    20  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    21  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    22  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    23  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef6a4 AGGraphGetInputValue + 236
    24  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107180a4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 2400
    25  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb82370 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 770544
    26  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb817ec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 767596
    27  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fce8678 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 92376
    28  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb84254 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 778452
    29  SwiftUI                             0x000000010facf4d0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 37712
    30  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcc513c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 2092988
    31  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcff954 __swift_allocate_boxed_opaque_existential_1 + 1300
    32  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    33  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    34  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    35  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef6a4 AGGraphGetInputValue + 236
    36  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110717f4c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 2056
    37  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb82370 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 770544
    38  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb817ec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 767596
    39  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fce85c4 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 92196
    40  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd0d10c block_destroy_helper + 6772
    41  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb845d8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 779352
    42  SwiftUI                             0x000000010facf538 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 37816
    43  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcc4f08 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 2092424
    44  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd0d0e0 block_destroy_helper + 6728
    45  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    46  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    47  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9a88 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 264
    48  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef6a4 AGGraphGetInputValue + 236
    49  SwiftUI                             0x000000010ff71fd8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 252
    50  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107fce48 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_17 + 216
    51  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e2f8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39456
    52  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e1e0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39176
    53  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f237c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 3056
    54  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f35f0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7780
    55  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071aa44 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 13056
    56  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110719cb4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 9584
    57  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071911c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 6616
    58  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071b45c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 15640
    59  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110718eac OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 5992
    60  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b51b70 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 2680
    61  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b522e8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 4592
    62  SwiftUI                             0x00000001102ea9bc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 87664
    63  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f3590 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7684
    64  SwiftUI                             0x00000001109e2140 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 3024
    65  SwiftUI                             0x00000001109e27f4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 4740
    66  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e2f8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39456
    67  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e1e0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39176
    68  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f3590 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7684
    69  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110153e48 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_7 + 1536
    70  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015455c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_7 + 3348
    71  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e2f8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39456
    72  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e1e0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39176
    73  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f3590 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7684
    74  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071a00c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 10440
    75  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071911c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 6616
    76  SwiftUI                             0x000000011071b45c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 15640
    77  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110718eac OUTLINED_FUNCTION_13 + 5992
    78  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b51b70 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 2680
    79  SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b522e8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_21 + 4592
    80  SwiftUI                             0x00000001102ea9bc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_83 + 87664
    81  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f3590 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7684
    82  SwiftUI                             0x000000011045f778 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_23 + 5328
    83  SwiftUI                             0x000000011045fe64 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_23 + 7100
    84  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e2f8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39456
    85  SwiftUI                             0x000000011015e1e0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 39176
    86  SwiftUI                             0x00000001107f3590 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_60 + 7684
    87  SwiftUI                             0x00000001101895cc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 25444
    88  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd55b0 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 14352
    89  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd51700 objectdestroy.6475Tm + 34384
    90  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    91  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    92  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    93  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    94  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb7312c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 708524
    95  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb73288 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 708872
    96  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd55b0 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 14352
    97  SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcfeffc __swift_mutable_project_boxed_opaque_existential_1 + 23620
    98  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    99  AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    100 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    101 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    102 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd3484 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 5860
    103 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    104 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    105 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    106 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    107 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fce3668 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 71880
    108 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    109 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    110 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    111 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    112 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb7312c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 708524
    113 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb737a8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 710184
    114 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd55b0 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 14352
    115 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcff100 __swift_mutable_project_boxed_opaque_existential_1 + 23880
    116 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    117 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    118 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    119 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    120 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb7312c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 708524
    121 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fb7399c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 710684
    122 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd55b0 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 14352
    123 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd6cee8 objectdestroy.3121Tm + 11472
    124 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    125 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    126 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    127 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    128 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcd3484 __swift_memcpy25_8 + 5860
    129 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    130 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    131 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    132 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    133 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110284a74 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 11864
    134 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110284b84 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 12136
    135 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fcf57b8 _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 416
    136 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    137 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    138 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    139 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    140 SwiftUI                             0x00000001109d1c6c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 9412
    141 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd54b18 objectdestroy.6475Tm + 47720
    142 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    143 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    144 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    145 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    146 SwiftUI                             0x00000001100a3c1c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_41 + 3204
    147 SwiftUI                             0x00000001100a3ff0 get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzAA13PreferenceKeyRd_0_r_0_lAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA24_AnchorTransformModifierVyqd__qd_0_GGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AhA0cJ0HPyHCHCTm + 196
    148 SwiftUI                             0x00000001100a41c0 get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzAA13PreferenceKeyRd_0_r_0_lAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA24_AnchorTransformModifierVyqd__qd_0_GGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AhA0cJ0HPyHCHCTm + 660
    149 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fdc49dc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_7 + 62956
    150 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    151 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    152 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    153 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    154 SwiftUI                             0x000000011029354c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_3 + 38624
    155 SwiftUI                             0x000000011057144c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 19908
    156 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fd96bec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_4 + 27032
    157 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    158 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    159 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd9b20 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 416
    160 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef8ec AGGraphGetValue + 216
    161 SwiftUI                             0x000000010ff68de4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_100 + 20980
    162 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110b98afc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_4 + 4808
    163 SwiftUI                             0x000000010ff68ccc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_100 + 20700
    164 SwiftUI                             0x000000010fdc49dc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_7 + 62956
    165 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd16f8 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 512
    166 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd1dd4 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 428
    167 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abd92c4 _ZN2AG5Graph9value_refENS_11AttributeIDEPK15AGSwiftMetadataRh + 160
    168 AttributeGraph                      0x000000012abef934 AGGraphGetValue + 288
    169 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110acac5c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_29 + 5632
    170 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110acae9c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_29 + 6208
    171 SwiftUI                             0x000000011096d0c4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 21444
    172 SwiftUI                             0x000000011096986c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 7020
    173 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110968724 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 2596
    174 SwiftUI                             0x00000001109688f0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 3056
    175 SwiftUI                             0x0000000110169be0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_3 + 1800
    176 SwiftUI                             0x000000011016a880 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_3 + 5032
    177 SwiftUI                             0x000000011016b68c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_3 + 8628
    178 SwiftUI                             0x000000011016b814 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_3 + 9020
    179 UIKitCore                           0x000000012705cecc -[UICollectionViewCell _performConfigurationStateUpdate] + 192
    180 UIKitCore                           0x0000000126ff90c0 -[UICollectionViewListCell _preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:] + 48
    181 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127023288 -[UICollectionView _checkForPreferredAttributesInView:originalAttributes:] + 156
    182 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127024650 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 1340
    183 UIKitCore                           0x000000012702bce4 -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForSingleCategoryAttributes:limitCreation:fadeForBoundsChange:] + 1056
    184 UIKitCore                           0x000000012702bff0 -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForAttributes:fadeForBoundsChange:notifyLayoutForVisibleCellsPass:] + 276
    185 UIKitCore                           0x000000012702a74c -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1572
    186 UIKitCore                           0x000000012702f3f4 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 300
    187 SwiftUI                             0x000000010ffaa3cc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_5 + 6620
    188 SwiftUI                             0x000000010ffaa584 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_5 + 7060
    189 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127cb9bc8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1920
    190 QuartzCore                          0x000000011390c844 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 440
    191 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127ca9ec8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 288
    192 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127a6c8a0 -[UISheetPresentationController _sheetLayoutInfoLayout:] + 28
    193 UIKitCore                           0x00000001270d04c4 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _layout] + 208
    194 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127a6dc4c __54-[UISheetPresentationController _transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke_3 + 32
    195 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127caf290 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 68
    196 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127a6dbbc __54-[UISheetPresentationController _transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
    197 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271bd2d4 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 228
    198 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271ba9e0 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] + 212
    199 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127caf0b0 __63+[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]_block_invoke + 28
    200 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c8b144 -[UIViewAnimationState _runAlongsideAnimations] + 32
    201 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c8a464 -[UIViewAnimationState pop] + 36
    202 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c88558 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 52
    203 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127cb0728 +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 580
    204 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127cb0a20 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 44
    205 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c84f40 __50-[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:]_block_invoke_2 + 136
    206 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127cb0dc8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) conditionallyAnimate:withAnimation:layout:completion:] + 80
    207 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c84bc0 -[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:] + 656
    208 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c84734 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1832
    209 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271b7ea4 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 1244
    210 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271bdb2c ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_3 + 44
    211 UIKitCore                           0x00000001272da334 +[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 88
    212 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271bdac8 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 168
    213 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127caefdc +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 148
    214 UIKitCore                           0x00000001271bd968 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 432
    215 UIKitCore                           0x00000001270c16a8 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_3 + 1500
    216 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c649f0 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 64
    217 UIKitCore                           0x0000000127c64e24 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 172
    218 UIKitCore                           0x000000012782d458 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 492
    219 UIKitCore                           0x000000012781f050 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 104
    220 UIKitCore                           0x00000001278495b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 80
    221 CoreFoundation                      0x000000010808917c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    222 CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108083b1c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 512
    223 CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108083fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 968
    224 CoreFoundation                      0x00000001080837f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
    225 GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ddf3c98 GSEventRunModal + 160
    226 UIKitCore                           0x00000001278205d4 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
    227 UIKitCore                           0x00000001278245cc UIApplicationMain + 124
    228 SwiftUI                             0x00000001109d6b18 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_51 + 496
    229 SwiftUI                             0x00000001109d69c0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_51 + 152
    230 SwiftUI                             0x000000011017a36c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_10 + 88
    231 stuffTracker                        0x0000000104cfa244 $s12stuffTracker0aB3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    232 stuffTracker                        0x0000000104cfa404 main + 12
    233 dyld                                0x0000000105f99fa0 start_sim + 20
    234 ???                                 0x0000000106165e50 0x0 + 4397096528
    235 ???                                 0x2543800000000000 0x0 + 2685130540331302912
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Menu does not have a valid element for default selection'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.13 - Device: iPhone 8 Plus (5E73D346-A020-40FA-A000-499687C0EC77) - Runtime: iOS 16.1 (20B72) - DeviceType: iPhone 8 Plus
```

Comment: Lowest-tech but maybe most reliable: Comment out pickers until you find the one causing the issue

Comment: @jnpdx thx but exactly that was NOT my question. I wanted to know how I can tell by reading the debug log